# R data.table join with inequality conditions between left and right table

Tags: r, data.table

I saw the question on join with inequality conditions [R data.table join with inequality conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053177/r-data-table-join-with-inequality-conditions) and I ask myself, how would we proceed to join two data.tables with an inequality condition between these two?

This is usually of great interest in time series, where we want to join one table X with another Y but the join should choose the first row in X that matches in a time frame smaller than the time of the row in Y.

```
dt <- data.table(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 4), 5:16)
dt2 <- data.table(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 4), 1:12)
cbind(dt,dt2)
    V1 V2 V1 V2
 1:  A  5  A  1
 2:  B  6  B  2
 3:  C  7  C  3
 4:  A  8  A  4
 5:  B  9  B  5
 6:  C 10  C  6
 7:  A 11  A  7
 8:  B 12  B  8
 9:  C 13  C  9
10:  A 14  A 10
11:  B 15  B 11
12:  C 16  C 12
```

Now, take the rows from `dt`that match the rows from `dt2` on the variable `V1` but have `dt$V2`smaller than `dt2$V2`.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `roll` argument here.

```
timeresolution = 0.01
dt[,V2 := V2 - timeresolution]

setkeyv(dt,c("V1","V2"))
setkeyv(dt2,c("V1","V2"))
dt2[dt,roll=-Inf]

> dt2[dt,roll=-Inf]
    V1 V2 V2.1
 1:  A  4    5
 2:  A  7    8
 3:  A 10   11
 4:  A 13   14
 5:  B  5    6
 6:  B  8    9
 7:  B 11   12
 8:  B 14   15
 9:  C  6    7
10:  C  9   10
11:  C 12   13
12:  C 15   16
```

Comment: I do not get the reason for using the V2.prev. Your approach also works with just using `dt`and `dt2`as they are: `dt2[dt, roll = -Inf]`

Comment: You're right. I wasn't sure how you want to treat the case where you might have the same `V1`,`V2` combination in both `dt` and `dt2` and used `V2prev` to counter that possibility.

Comment: Nevertheless, your approach by using the `roll` argument helps me in solving such problems.